# How to call a method that takes a char array as a parameter

Tags: c#, arrays, methods

I have a reshuffle method that is of string type and it takes a char array as an argument it must randomize the characters inside the array each time the Encrypt method is used .. when I tried to call it in another method it gives me the syntax error "Method has some invalid arguments" This is the code

```
char[] p = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };
string reshuffle(char[] alpas)
        {
            Random random=new Random();
            for (int t = 0; t < alpas.Length; t++)
            {
                char tmp = alpas[t];
                int r = random.Next(t, alpas.Length);
                alpas[t] = alpas[r];
                alpas[r] = tmp;
            }
            return new string (alpas);
        }
public string Encrypt(string pt)
        {
            reshuffledChars=reshuffle(p[25]);
            char[] ch = reshuffledChars.ToCharArray();
            char[] buffer = new char[(pt.Length)];
            for(int i=0;i<pt.Length;i++)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<26;j++)
                {
                    if (char.ToUpper(p[j]) == pt[i])
                    {
                        buffer[i] = char.ToUpper(ch[j]);
                        break;
                    }
                    else if(char.ToLower(p[j])==pt[i])
                    {
                        buffer[i] = char.ToLower(ch[j]);
                        break;
                    }
                    else if(pt[i]==' ')
                    {
                        buffer[i] = ' ';
                    }
                }
            }
            return new string(buffer);
        }
```

Comment: On the first line of `Encrypt`, you pass `p[25]` to `reshuffle()`. `p[25]` is of type `char`, not type `char[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing `reshuffle(p[25])`, which is a single `char`, you should pass the entire array, like so: `reshuffle(p)`.

Answer (score 0):

In this line:
"reshuffledChars=reshuffle(p[25]);"
p[25] returns a char

Answer (score 0):

This line in `Encrypt()`:

```
reshuffle(p[25]);
```

should (I'm assuming) be:

```
reshuffle(p);
```

You're passing a `char` not a `char[]` to `reshuffle()` -- `p[25]` is the last `char` in the array `p`.

BTW if `p` should remain unchanged you'll need to copy it before passing to `reshuffle`.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing wrong parameters instead of  `reshuffle(p[25])` use `reshuffle(p)` to send entire array.

If you are looking for a random string generator, [this link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qrTkAG) will help. I have provided a working example in dotnet fiddle.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace Rextester
{
   public class Program
   {
    private static Random random = new Random();

    public static string RandomString(int length)
    {
        const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!@#$%&";
        return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, length)
          .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Your code goes here
        Console.WriteLine(RandomString(8));
    }
  }
}
```